# Discord.js check warnings command bug

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

```
const Mongodb = require('../../models/modSchema');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'warnings',
    category: "moderation",
    description: 'Finds and displays the warnings of the mentioned user.',
    run : async(client, message, args, db) => {
        const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);

        if(!mentionedMember) return message.channel.send("bruh mention a member u nub");

        Mongodb.find({ guildId : message.guild.id, userId : mentionedMember.user.id}, async(err, data) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            if(data) {
                message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(`${mentionedMember.user.tag}'s punishments.`)
                    .addFields(
                        data.map((warn)=> {
                            if (!warn || warn === undefined) return { name: 'Punishments', value: 'This user has no punishments' };
                            if (warn) return { name: `Case #${warn.case} - ${warn.punishType}`, value: warn.reason};
                        })
                    )
                    .setColor("GREEN")
                )
            } 
        });
    }
}
```

This is my code.
Whenever I type `-warnings user` and the user has no warns then it replies with `user's warn` when it's supposed to reply with `This user has no warnings`. Another question I have is how to make the bot show the user's warnings when the user says `-warnings` it shows the current user's warnings meaning that the user that said `-warnings`.

Comment: For your 2nd question (As I'm not the greatest with MongoDB at the moment), you can define mentionedMember as: `const mentionedMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.mentions.members.first() || message.member;` - That would result in taking the GuildMember object of the author of the message if there wasn't a member found using an ID or a mention.

Comment: I'm not sure what your database returns but if I'm correct it returns an array of sorts that can be empty if no warnings are present. The problem then would be your check. You only check if warn exists or if it's undefined. The problem is that an empty array is still `truthy` so it won't trigger the if statement. Try to check for length instead.

Comment: Yes, but then what would the command handler be. What statement

Comment: How do I check for the length?

Comment: `if(data.length < 1) return { name: 'Punishments' ...} else return data.map(() => ...)`

Comment: what cursed said but keep in mind that it may not be an array at all. It was an educated guess on my part.

Comment: I understand I'll test it right now.

Comment: I have one question with the first command handler is that saying that when there is a warn on the user or if there isn't a warn on the user